# Why is it not possible to wait for a Qt process to finish in a static destructor?

Tags: c++, qt

The following piece of code starts a process that takes one second to finish, and subsequently waits for that process to finish before exiting. For some reason, the following code hangs in `p->waitForFinished()` even though the process did finish.

```
#include <QtCore/QProcess>    

class A
{
  public:
    A():
        p(0)
    {
    }

    ~A()
    {
        p->waitForFinished();
        delete p;
    }

    void start()
    {
        p = new QProcess(0);
        p->start("sleep 1");
    }

    QProcess *p;
};

int main(void)
{
  static A a;
  a.start();

  return 0;
}
```

However, as soon as `a` is not declared statically, but as follows:

```
A a;
```

the `waitForFinished()` call succeeds. Is this a Qt bug, or is this expected behavour? My suspicion is that some kind of logic required to detect whether an application successfully finished is already destroyed once the destructor of `A` is called.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have tried to clean up the thread created by `QProcess` two different ways at the same time, so this is a bug in your program.

You've detached the thread by returning from `main` (which terminates all threads in the process, detaching them if they are joinable).

And you've cleaned up the `QProcess` thread by joining it through `waitForFinished`.

You can detach a thread or you can join it, but you can't do both, even indirectly. Apparently, the detach wins, and the join hangs.

Most likely this is because `QProcess` uses its own termination signal rather than the one built into the threading library. So the return from `main` terminates the thread before it can send that termination signal, leaving the `waitForFinished` function to wait for a signal that will never be sent.

As a general rule, threads should not be created in constructors nor cleaned up in destructors. This is primarily because the timing of these operations requires more explicit control than is possible. And they should never be created before `main` starts nor cleaned up after `main` returns -- again because you need to control the context in which these things happen.